# Is it possible to change original html text in php?

Tags: php

I am trying to make "manner friendly" website. We use different declination dependent on gender and other factors. For example:

```
You did = robili
It did = robilo
She did = robila
```

Linguisticaly this is very simplified (and unlucky) example! I would like to change html text in php file where appropriate. For example

```
<? php
something
?>

html text of the page and somewhere is the word "robil"
<div>we tried to robil^i|o|a^</div>

<? php something ?>
```

Now I would like to replace all occurences of different tokens ^*characters*|*characters*|*characters*^ and replace them by one of their internal values according to "gender".

It is easy in javascript on the client side, but you will see all this weird "tokenizing" before javascript replace it.
Here I do not know the elegant solution.

Or do you have better idea?

Thanks for advice.

Comment: You haven't given us all the details. Are the characters always the same, or does it vary per word? Are there always three characters to choose form? Etc. Anyway, this should be very simple in PHP, you cannot get more basic than this.

Comment: Take a look on Twig. It will help you a lot

Comment: @KIKOSoftware There are many words (but not definitely most of them) like this and they have different declination rules, so I have to manualy edit whole text, and add these tokens: ^si|sa|ste^,    ^mal|mala|malo^ and so on... where it is needed. 
My concern is to change html text within php file without using another php helper file, which would change this one.

Comment: so this text is not on some database?

Comment: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html. This's based on preg_math of cause, but far more readable then.

Comment: @jaro1989 no it is plain simple HTML/php file... thanks for your hints, I will check them later. :-) Replacing is not a issue this time, the problem is HTML modification inside the file.

Comment: There's another cool thing called I18n. But you can use it not for countries, but for genders. https://github.com/Philipp15b/php-i18n. A lot o work here, but this's just another approach.

Comment: And yeah, think about of moving your html-s to some templates. It will save a lot of time further.

Comment: @jaro1989 I try hard not to work harder... Thanx ;-)

Comment: It's not a joke, really. Just sum all the approaches you have and choose the best one with cons/props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add these scripts before and after the HTML:

```
<?php

// start output buffering
ob_start();

?>
<html>
<body>
html text of the page and somewhere is the word "robil"
<div>we tried to robil^i|o|a^, but also vital^si|sa|ste^, borko^mal|mala|malo^ </div>
</body>
</html>
<?php

$use  = 1; // indicate which declination to use (0,1 or 2)

// get buffered html
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

// match anything between '^' than's not a control chr or '^', min 5 and max 20 chrs.
if (preg_match_all('/\^[^[:cntrl:]\^]{3,20}\^/',$html,$matches))
{
  // replace all
  foreach (array_unique($matches[0]) as $match)
  {
    $choices = explode('|',trim($match,'^'));
    $html    = str_replace($match,$choices[$use],$html);
  }
}

echo $html;
```

This returns:

> html text of the page and somewhere is the word "robil" we tried to
>   robilo, but also vitalsa, borkomala

Comment: I normally don't like regular expressions, because they are hard to read, but it is by far the easiest thing to use here. To learn what the regular expression does see also: https://regex101.com Remember that the same can also be achieved without using a regular expression, it would just need a tiny bit more code, and might be a bit slower.

Comment: you are very nice. Thank you for your answer. The crucial question is, if it is the ONLY way to put original HTML into string. Because then it is not HTML, but string itself :-(.
I was considering to write loader php script, which would modify original html/php file (using simple_html_dom.php), but it is overhead...

Comment: You can buffer all html output with output buffering: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php then at the end of the page you add my php script, process the HTML and send it to the client. I'll modify my script accordingly, hold on...

Comment: Done... Don't add these scripts in all HTML files, just make two PHP files called 'start.php' and 'finish.php' and include them at the top and bottom of each HTML file: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Exactly this was my intention, and it leads to the loader php script. 
<?php
    ob_start();
    include $TemplateHTMLFile;
    $str = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $str = yourfunction($str);
    echo $str;
?>
But this means, that this script has to run outside original HTML/php file. 
Or is it somehow possible to modify it prior dispatch to the client?????

Comment: As I said, the only way to use the original HTML file is to include two PHP scripts at the begin and end of those HTML files. I don't know of a way to insert a PHP script into a HTML file without putting the PHP file into the HTML file. Perhaps it is possible with .htaccess files, but I don't want to go there. ;-)

Comment: KIKO. Yes, you are a exceptionally great man... :-) You healed my wounds for today. You have a big point from me... Thanks much much...

Comment: You're welcome. I think it's Polish, isn't it? Just remember that the maximum of 20 characters I used, limits you to a declination of maximal 5 characters. If it is longer you need to increase the maximum.

Comment: I think that server will fall after 10 - 15 user's attempts to use such code. I think that even 1 is enough if your text is huge one. You can't cache your results as they're dynamic. Please, be aware of it.

Comment: @jaro1989: Not if you rent a decent server. :-) Yes, you're right, it is a load, but you would be surprised what a good server can handle. I have always found I could do a lot of string manipulations, without much load on my server. The thing that always gets me is database access, that's eating resources.

Comment: decent is server is great. @lyborko has you one for your site? Agree with you about good server, but people must think about load every time they are doing something huge.